# How to stop a Month calculation in php when certain value is reached

Tags: php

I have depreciation system that consist only two values of months 48 and 96.

based on that 48 or 96 values i need to know How to stop a calculation in php when a ceratin value is reached (48/96)?

so i have this script to show how many months has passed.

```
<?php 
$depreciation = ($tom['depreciation_age']);  <----- 48 or 96 
$date = date("Y-m-d");
$timeStart = strtotime($tom['purchase_date']);
$timeEnd = strtotime("$date");
$number = 0 + (date("Y",$timeEnd)-date("Y",$timeStart))*12;
if ($number >= $depreciation) {
    echo $ depreciation;
  } else {
  echo $number;
 }  
?>
```

If the months over 48 or 96 values i use IF function to make them 48 or 96, but i have another column that need this value from the script above. the value from the calculation above will continue to calculate because it's based on present date.

```
<?php 

$a = ($tom['depreciation_permonth']);
$b = $number;
$total = $a * $b;
echo $total;

?>
```

how to stop it, please help

this is what people should see in the browser

```
id    name       date        price   Depre_month  depreciation_permonth  asset_age  depreciation_accumulation
1     car        2013-08-01  50000      48               1.041,7          48         50000
2     boat       2012-03-22  45000      48                 937.5          48         45000
3     computer   2015-09-01   2000      48                  41.6          24         1000
```

Comment: What has this got to do with MySQL?

Comment: because the data is in MySql, I calculate how many months has passed by using a data in mysql that consist of nama, date, price, etc, so i took today's date -  purchase date = ... months

Comment: There's no data. No query. And no result. So there's nothing here that relates to SQL. I would suggest you either provide that information, or remove the tag.